# SELECT inner joined columns where only one column can not have duplicate record

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I want to select inner joined tables, and if there is a duplicate record in 'column D', do not display entire inner joined row.

Table 1

```
a b 
1 car
1 boat
1 man
```

Table 2

```
c  d
1  dog   *dog is a duplicate, so only display it once. 
1  dog
1  cat
```

Here is my inner joined sql select statement so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a b c d FROM 
table1 INNER JOIN 
table2 ON table1.a = table2.c
WHERE <duplicate> NOT ALREADY IN RESULT
```

Result should be:

```
1 car 1 dog
*1 boat 1 dog* <--dog is a duplicate so should not be displayed
1 man 1 cat
```

Comment: That output is impossible to get. If you remove dog, what goes in it's place? And joining in a=1, c=1 with DISTINCT will give 6 rows in the output because that is how JOINS work. Now, proper data and a proper question please

Comment: Right -- whey wouldn't you get `1 boat 1 cat` in your output? Your sample output is probably incorrect.

Comment: Agree with gbn - this is not a JOIN key-based join - seems more like a join based on tuple position. BTW, please mark EDITs when you make them. My (deleted) answer was written BEFORE you put the "result should be".

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with asp.net.  If that's correct, please remove the tag.

Comment: @user719825: can you fix the data or the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want some arbitrary pairs drawn from the two tables, as long as the second column does not have any repeated values.  Whether you get car/dog or boat/dog is unspecified, you just don't want to get both.

```
declare @Table1 table ( id1 Int, value1 VarChar(8) )
insert into @Table1 ( id1, value1 ) values ( 1, 'car' )
insert into @Table1 ( id1, value1 ) values ( 1, 'boat' )
insert into @Table1 ( id1, value1 ) values ( 1, 'man' )

declare @Table2 table ( id2 Int, value2 VarChar(8) )
insert into @Table2 ( id2, value2 ) values ( 1, 'dog' )
insert into @Table2 ( id2, value2 ) values ( 1, 'dog' )
insert into @Table2 ( id2, value2 ) values ( 1, 'cat' )

-- All combinations.
select value1, value2, Row_Number() over ( order by value2 ) as 'RowNumber'
  from @Table1 as L inner join @Table2 as R on L.id1 = R.id2

-- Some combinations in which values in the second column do not recur.
select value1, value2
  from ( select value1, value2, Row_Number() over ( order by value2 ) as 'RowNumber'
    from @Table1 as L inner join @Table2 as R on L.id1 = R.id2 ) as Blue
  where RowNumber = ( select min( RowNumber ) from
    ( select value1, value2, Row_Number() over ( order by value2 ) as 'RowNumber'
    from @Table1 as L inner join @Table2 as R on L.id1 = R.id2 ) as Grey where value2 = Blue.value2 )
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't look much like the expected result. It also have duplicates. Seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this is what he is looking for, thx for the hasty minus. Notice i only changed the test data since it seemed wrong.

```
declare @t1 table(a int, b varchar(5)) 
declare @t2 table(c int, d varchar(5)) 

insert @t1 
select 1, 'car'  union all--*
select 2, 'boat' union all--*
select 3, 'man'

insert @t2
select 1, 'dog' union all--*
select 2, 'dog' union all--*
select 2, 'dog' union all--*
select 3, 'cat'

SELECT 
a, b, c, d FROM 
@t1 t1 INNER JOIN 
@t2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.c
GROUP BY a,b,c,d
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Added "all" to my unions thanks to JNK's sharp eye

Comment: gnb I dissagree on the minus you gave me. I took the sql and changed it to the right syntax for the problem and just didn't verify that the test data was wrong

Comment: I agree that this is probably the correct answer given the state of the question; +1. Don't worry about -1s!

Comment: You also are not creating dupes since you use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` - do a `SELECT * FROM @t2` and see that the dupe is already out

Comment: JNK you are right, problem was that i recieved -1 for my solution because I had not included testdata. So I posted the test data to show I had the right solution. What is funny is that i got -1 twice and +1 twice now

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: you've made an assumption. I can't find it, but this kind of "shape" question has been asked before where OP doesn't understand sets.

Comment: @gbn I looked at the problem definition and didn't bother to look at the test data. I corrected the sql to do what was described. My solution was correct. His data was bad. You gave me minus. I didn't deserve that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am the OP and I understand setting @variables. I wanted to avoid using variables, and just use a select with case statements. But you guys worked hard, and this solution is good enough. Its  also my fault that I didnt specify in the original post that I didn't want to use variables.

Comment: @user719825: the table variables are for sample data where t-clausen.dk guessed at what you really meant. Read the comments on your question please

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
table1.a, table1.b, tab2.c, tab2.d 
FROM
table1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT table2.c, table2.d AS tab2) ON table1.a = tab2.c
GROUP BY tab2.d
```